# React `act` warning on DidMount and Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Okay so I have this bunch of code that's is thrown on `useEffect(() => {...}, [])` a.k.a `componentDidMount`.

```js
// utils/apiCalls.ts

export const loadData = async <T>(
  url: string,
  errorMsg = "Couldn't retrieve data.",
): Promise<T> => {
  const res = await fetch(url, { mode: 'cors', credentials: 'include' });
  if (res.ok) return await res.json();
  throw new Error(errorMsg);
};

export const loadChat = (id: number): Promise<IChat> => {
  return loadData<IChat>(
    `${CHAT_API}/${id}/nested/`,
    "We couldn't get the chat.",
  );
};
```

```js
// components/MessageContainer.tsx

const MessageContainer = (/* props */) => {
  /*
   * Some coding...
   */

  useEffect(() => {
  if (session === null) return;
  if (chat === null) {
    loadChat(session.chat).then(setChat).catch(alert);
    return;
  }
  // More coding...
}, [session, chat]);
};
```

The problem comes when I try to test it with `@testing-library/react` since it gives me this warning `Warning: An update to MessagesContainer inside a test was not wrapped in act(...)`.

**How can I make a correct test for this?**
Here's the test I have right now.

```js
// tests/MessagesContainer.spec.tsx

describe('MessagesContainer suite', () => {
  it('loads messages on mount', () => {
    fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(ChatMock));
    render(
      <SessionContext.Provider value={SessionMock}>
        <MessagesContainer {...MessagesContainerMockedProps} />
      </SessionContext.Provider>,
    );

    expect(fetchMock.mock.calls.length).toEqual(1);
  });
});
```

**NOTE**: Wrapping render on `act` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

`fetch` is async function which finished only all regular script execution ends. You need to really await `fetch` finished before call `expect`.
Moreover, it is not recommend to use `testing-library` as you did. You want to check how element rendered after `fetch`, write you test accordance to exception result in UI.
For instance, if after fetching you expect something like this:

```html
<span>message</span>
```

you expect span with message, and test will be:

```js
expect(screen.findByText('message'));
```

Comment: Ended up moving everything to the parent component (so logic is more correct since it doesn't have to receive  a WebSocket as Prop)

Answer (score 0):

So at the end I used `waitFor` in order to check if element has been mounted.

```js
// tests/ChatMessagesContainer.spec.tsx

describe('ChatMessagesContainer suite', () => {
  it('renders multiple messages', async () => {
    const messageMock = Object.assign({}, MessageMock);
    messageMock.message = faker.lorem.words();
    const chatMock = Object.assign({}, ChatMock);
    chatMock.chat_message_set = [MessageMock, messageMock];
    fetchMock.mockResponseOnce(JSON.stringify(chatMock));
    const { getAllByText } = render(
      <AuthContext.Provider value={UserMock}>
        <SessionContext.Provider value={SessionMock}>
          <MessagesContainer {...MessagesContainerMockedProps} />
        </SessionContext.Provider>
      </AuthContext.Provider>,
    );

    // THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART
    expect(await screen.findByText(MessageMock.message)).toBeInTheDocument();
    expect(getAllByText(MessageMock.author.username).length).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

This article was really useful [Maybe you don't need `act`](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/you-probably-dont-need-act-in-your-react-tests-2a0bcd2ad65c).